# Add today's date from numbers of days entered in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am looking for some javascript where the user enters a number into a input box in a form then it calucates the date from today's date

For example

User enters 10
Then it shows the date as 17/03/2013

10 days ahead of today's date

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I haven't to be honest, I can obviously do the form for the number of days input box

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = new Date();
result.setDate(result.getDate() + 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var add_days = parseInt(document.getElementById('text1').value);
var now = new Date();
now.setDate(now.getDate()+add_days);
alert(now); // Display this now to wherever you want
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I neeed the user to enter the number of days (10 on the example above) and need the result to show on  the page, not via a text box

Answer (score 0):

You should add de amount of days to javascript class Date;

```
var addDays = $('#addDaysText').text();
var currentDate = new Date(); //get current date
var futureDate = currentDate() + addDays;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of those answers will work, unless you start crossing month lines. For example, if today is the 8th, and you add 10, you will get the 18th, but if today is the 24th and you add 10, you will get the 34th!

The right way to do this is to convert it to an absolute time format, add the unit, then convert back.

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
var diff = 10; // days
var futureTime = now + 10*24*60*60*1000; // 24 hrs/day, 60 mins/hr, 60 sec/min, 1000 ms/sec
var future = new Date(futureTime);
```

If you want to start doing some really strange stuff, I would recommend using a library. I authored one for browser and/or nodejs use a while back https://github.com/deitch/jsorm-i18n